# Mako with Unicode UTF 16

Tags: python, python-unicode, mako

I am using python 2.7 and Mako to generate a docbook file. The generation is done as follows:

```
theTemp = Template(filename="default.docbook.mako_template.xml",  
    input_encoding='utf-16',
    output_encoding='utf-16',
    encoding_errors='replace')

ctx = Context(outfile)
ctx.xml = someXmlString

theTemp.render_context( ctx )
```

I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\my-rest-api-py\__init__.py", line 315, in go
    theTemp.render_context( ctx )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\template.py", line 466, in render_context
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\runtime.py", line 835, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\runtime.py", line 860, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "to_docbook_default_docbook_mako_template_xml", line 22, in render_body
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What else do I need to make sure Mako reads/write in utf16?

Comment: *Any* chance that files has `## -*- coding: ascii -*-` as a header? Also try forcing it to UTF-16 with `## -*- coding: utf-16 -*-`; maybe that will help.

Comment: You could try `render_unicode()`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass it a `Context`.